# Последовательная замена существующего ImageView из ArrayList<Bitmap>

Tags: android

Делаю свой Adapter и возник такой вопрос, адаптер использует inflate метод для xml файла, где нужно подгружать картинку и текст, с текстом всё нормально, а вот как подгрузить в ImageView готовую ImageView из ранее созданного ArrayList?

Правка: Сделал вместо ImageView Bitmap. В итоге приложение крашится со словами

java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Видимо не может добавить в Image Bitmap.
Код адаптера:

```
public class customAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
ArrayList<Drawer_items> items=new ArrayList<Drawer_items>();
public Context context;
public customAdapter(Context context){
    this.context=context;
}
public void add(Drawer_items item){
    items.add(item);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void clear(){
    items.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Drawer_items drawer_items=items.get(position);
    LinearLayout linearLayout=(LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.drawable_list_item, parent, false);
    ImageView imageView=(ImageView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.host_picture);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(drawer_items.getIcons(position));//назначение изображения
    TextView textView=(TextView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.drawer_text);
    textView.setText(drawer_items.getNames(position))//назначение текста
    return linearLayout;
}
```

}

Объявлённый Bitmap:

```
Bitmap[] icons=new Bitmap[3];
    icons[0]= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_library_music_black_24dp);
    icons[1]= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_library_music_black_24dp);
    icons[2]= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_library_music_black_24dp);
    ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps=new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    for(int i=0; i<icons.length; ++i){
        bitmaps.add(icons[i]);
    }
```

Объявлённый текст:

```
public ArrayList<String> mDrawer;
String [] labels=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer);
    for(int i=0; i<labels.length; ++i){
        mDrawer.add(labels[i]);
    }
```

Добавление информации в адаптер:

```
 Drawer_items drawer_items=new Drawer_items(mDrawer,getApplicationContext(),bitmaps);
    customAdapter.add(drawer_items);
    mListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

За код не ругайте, я совсем ещё новичок.

Answer (score 1):

`ImageView` в `ArrayList` ни в коем случае хранить нельзя.

Если в `ArrayList` картинки типа `Bitmap` то загрузить их можно при помощи `setImageBitmap();`

Comment: картинки как и все находятся в Drawable. Могу я узнать почему нельзя хранить сразу объект ImageView в ArrayList?

Comment: Есть несколько причин, в основном связанные с нееффективностью, лишним расходом памяти и потеницальными утечками памяти. Давайте лучше вы выложите код вашего адаптера и обсудим как лучше сделать.